# Loading data to JSON file using globals() inside static method does not work inside the class but it works outside the class, why?

Tags: python, json, class, static-methods, global

This is my class in a file resepi.py:

```
class resepi:
    def __init__ (self, serial_number):
        serial_number = int(serial_number)
        self.serial_number = serial_number;
        self.ftp, self.type = ftp(serial_number);
        self.folder = 'C:\\Users\\17037\\Documents\\' + str(serial_number)
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def save():
        all_units_info = {name: eval(name).__dict__ for name in list(globals()) if isinstance(eval(name), resepi)}
        with open('resepi_log_all.json', 'w') as file:
            json.dump(all_units_info, file, indent=4)
        print(all_units_info)
```

Then while trying to call it in the command line:

```
>>> from resepi import resepi
>>> import json
>>> unit_35844 = resepi(35844)
>>> unit_35861 = resepi(35861)
>>> unit_35780 = resepi(35780)
>>> resepi.save()
{}
```

and nothing is saved into the json file.

But if I make a function that does literally the exact same thing (I think):

```
>>> def save2():
...     all_units_info = {name: eval(name).__dict__ for name in list(globals()) if isinstance(eval(name), resepi)}
...     with open('resepi_log_all.json', 'w') as file:
...         json.dump(all_units_info, file, indent = 4)
...     print(all_units_info)
... 
>>> save2()
{'unit_35844': {'serial_number': 35844, 'ftp': 'N:\\!Factory_calibrations_and_tests\\RESEPI\\ROCK\\ROCK R2A (NSA)\\ROCK-R35844 (new design)\\', 'type': 'ROCK\\ROCK R2A (NSA)', 'folder': 'C:\\Users\\17037\\Documents\\35844'}, 'unit_35861': {'serial_number': 35861, 'ftp': 'N:\\!Factory_calibrations_and_tests\\RESEPI\\ROCK\\ROCK R2A (NSA)\\ROCK-R35861 (new design)\\', 'type': 'ROCK\\ROCK R2A (NSA)', 'folder': 'C:\\Users\\17037\\Documents\\35861'}, 'unit_35780': {'serial_number': 35780, 'ftp': 'N:\\!Factory_calibrations_and_tests\\RESEPI\\ROCK\\ROCK R2A (NSA)\\ROCK-R35780 (new design)\\', 'type': 'ROCK\\ROCK R2A (NSA)', 'folder': 'C:\\Users\\17037\\Documents\\35780'}}
```

it saves it like it is supposed to (and the json file matches the output).

Why does the same function (I think) work outside of a class but not inside of the class?

Comment: Dude I explained to you in the other question, `globals()` gives you the *modules globals where it is called*, see which is in `resepi.py`

Comment: BTW, **there's no need for `eval` and it could be wrong, so don't do `{name: eval(name).__dict__ for name in list(globals()) if isinstance(eval(name), resepi)}` just do `{name: value for name, value in globals().items() if isinstance(value, respi)}`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was under the impression that they were unrelated, although it seems obvious that they are now. Would you please respond to the comment in the other question then?